# Symfony Doctrine fetch EAGER and orderBy combination doesn't work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, yaml, symfony

I have a tree of pages. I would like to get all the sub-pages of a page. For that case I added the `fetch: Eager` to my yaml-file. I also want to order the sub-pages by their position. But the `fetch` seems to ruin everything. It does lower the amount of total executed queries, but the sub-pages aren't ordered by their position anymore.

This part is inside my yaml-file for the Page entity:

```
oneToMany:
    pages:
        targetEntity: Page
        mappedBy: parentPage
        fetch: EAGER
        orderBy: { position: ASC }
```

Any idea how to get all the pages of a page, but still order by the position? The tree of pages can be nested more than 1 level.

```
- page_1
    page_1_1
    page_1_2
        page_1_2_1
        page_1_2_2
- page_2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. When I use fetch mode EAGER doctrine creates one query with left joins instead of two queries and ignores ordering silently without notice. The solutions is use LAZY mode, but yes it's less effective.